# Extract date between single quotes in ruby

Tags: regex, ruby

I have a string like this:

```
ticket:1 priority:5 delay:'2019-08-31 02:53:27.720422' delay:'2019-08-30 00:04:10.681242'
```

I successfully extracted `ticket` and `priority` but failed on `delay`.

What I want is to extract delays as array so output will be like this:

```
#delays =>
[
  "delay:'2019-08-31 02:53:27.720422'",
  "delay:'2019-08-30 00:04:10.681242'"
]
```

What I've tried so far?

```
str = "ticket:1 priority:5 delay:'2019-08-31 02:53:27.720422' delay:'2019-08-30 00:04:10.681242'"
delays = str.scan(/delay:\w+(?:'\w+)*/).flatten
```

How can i extract them in my case? Note that, there is no guarantee that date format will be like in examples. Date format can be anything. So we should focus on strings between single quotes.

---

If possible result can be like this (so that i dont have to extract date again.):

```
#delays =>
[
  "2019-08-31 02:53:27.720422",
  "2019-08-30 00:04:10.681242"
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This expression might be close to what you have in mind:

```
\bdelay\s*:\s*['][^']*[']
```

In case you had other chars such as `"` for the `delay` values, it would go in the char class:

```
\bdelay\s*:\s*['"][^'"]*['"]
```

or:

```
\bdelay\s*:\s*'(\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2})\s*([^']*)'
```

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/oZd2LA/1/)

or:

```
\bdelay\s*:\s*'(\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}\s*[^']*)'
```

#### [Demo 3](https://regex101.com/r/FpeMDD/1/)

or more simplified:

```
\bdelay\s*:\s*'([^']*)'
```

#### Test

```
re = /\bdelay\s*:\s*'([^']*)'/
str = 'ticket:1 priority:5 delay:\'2019-08-31 02:53:27.720422\' delay:\'2019-08-30 00:04:10.681242\''

str.scan(re) do |match|
    puts match.to_s
end
```

#### Output

```
["2019-08-31 02:53:27.720422"]
["2019-08-30 00:04:10.681242"]
```

---

> If you wish to explore/simplify/modify the expression, it's been
>   explained on the top right panel of
>   [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/faFhL3/1/). If you'd like, you
>   can also watch in [this
>   link](https://regex101.com/r/faFhL3/1/debugger), how it would match
>   against some sample inputs.

---

Comment: Worked beautifully. Just a question. If string matches (starts) with `delay`, is it possible to return only date part inside single quotes? Or scan does return all matches at once? I am watching online demo now. -- I've wrapped second part with parenthesis and it grouped.

Comment: Similar to that. This will work for another part of my code but i just updated question. You may take a look at the bottom

Comment: Hm.. Do we need to strictly define lengths here? Because -im very sorry for this- i forgot to mention that, the date format can be different on each delay. There is no guarantee that user will enter in this format so delay can be -for example- like this: `delay:'01-10-2019'`. or many more formats like this.The main idea is here that, i accept anything between single quotes. which starts with `delay:`

Comment: Wow. thats worked! Thank you, Emma. Answer is accepted. (three of them)

Answer (score 2):

This is a suggestion for how you might extract all values of interest, not just the values for `"delay"`. It permits any number of instances of `"delay:'..."` in the string.

```
str = "ticket:1 priority:5 delay:'2019-08-31 02:53:27.720422' delay:'2019-08-30 00:04:10.681242"
```

```
str.delete("'").
    split(/ +(?=ticket|priority|delay)/).
    each_with_object({}) do |s,h|
      key, value = s.split(':', 2)
      case key
      when 'delay'
        (h[key] ||= []) << value
      else
        h[key] = value
      end
    end
  #=> {"ticket"=>"1", "priority"=>"5",
  #    "delay"=>["2019-08-31 02:53:27.720422", "2019-08-30 00:04:10.681242"]}
```

The regular expression that is `String#split`'s argument reads, "match one or more spaces followed immediately by the string `"ticket"`, `"priority"` or `"delay"`, the expression

```
(?=ticket|priority|delay)
```

being a *positive lookahead*.

The steps are as follows.

```
a = str.delete("'")
  #=> "ticket:1 priority:5 delay:2019-08-31 02:53:27.720422 delay:2019-08-30 00:04:10.681242"
```

```
b = a.split(/ +(?=ticket|priority|delay)/)
  #=> ["ticket:1", "priority:5", "delay:2019-08-31 02:53:27.720422",
  #    "delay:2019-08-30 00:04:10.681242"] 
c = b.each_with_object({}) do |s,h|
      key, value = s.split(':', 2)
      case key
      when 'delay'
        (h[key] ||= []) << value
      else
        h[key] = value
       end
     end
  #=> {"ticket"=>"1", "priority"=>"5",
  #    "delay"=>["2019-08-31 02:53:27.720422", "2019-08-30 00:04:10.681242"]}
```

Let's examine more closely the calculation of `c`.

```
enum = b.each_with_object({})
  #=> #<Enumerator: ["ticket:1", "priority:5", "delay:2019-08-31 02:53:27.720422",
  #      "delay:2019-08-30 00:04:10.681242"]:each_with_object({})>
```

The first value is generated by this enumerator and passed to the block, and the two block variables are assigned these values using array decompostion.

```
 s, h = enum.next
   #=> ["ticket:1", {}] 
 s #=> "ticket:1" 
 h #=> {}
```

The block calculation is then performed.

```
key, value = s.split(':', 2)
  #=> ["ticket", "1"] 
key
  #=> "ticket" 
value
  #=> "1"
```

`case else` applies, so

```
h[key] = value
  #=> h["ticket"] = 1
h #=> {"ticket"=>"1"}
```

The next element is generated by `enum`, the block variables are assigned values and block calculation is performed.

```
s, h = enum.next
  #=> ["priority:5", {"ticket"=>"1"}] 
key, value = s.split(':', 2)
  #=> ["priority", "5"]
```

`case else` again applies, so we execute

```
h[key] = value
  #=> h["priority"] = "5" 
h #=> {"ticket"=>"1", "priority"=>"5"}
```

Next,

```
s, h = enum.next
  #=> ["delay:2019-08-31 02:53:27.720422", {"ticket"=>"1", "priority"=>"5"}] 
key, value = s.split(':', 2)
  #=> ["delay", "2019-08-31 02:53:27.720422"]
```

`case "delay"` now applies, so we compute

```
(h[key] ||= []) << value
  #=> h[key] = (h[key] || []) << value
  #=> h["delay"] = (h["delay"] || []) << "2019-08-31 02:53:27.720422"
  #=> h["delay"] = (nil || []) << "2019-08-31 02:53:27.720422" 
  #=> h["delay"] = [] << "2019-08-31 02:53:27.720422
  #=> h["delay"] = ["2019-08-31 02:53:27.720422] 
h #=> {"ticket"=>"1", "priority"=>"5", "delay"=>["2019-08-31 02:53:27.720422"]}
```

Lastly,

```
s, h = enum.next
  #=> ["delay:2019-08-30 00:04:10.681242",
  #    {"ticket"=>"1", "priority"=>"5", "delay"=>["2019-08-31 02:53:27.720422"]}] 
key, value = s.split(':', 2)
  #=> ["delay", "2019-08-30 00:04:10.681242"] 
(h[key] ||= []) << value
  #=> ["2019-08-31 02:53:27.720422", "2019-08-30 00:04:10.681242"] 
h #=> {"ticket"=>"1", "priority"=>"5",
  #    "delay"=>["2019-08-31 02:53:27.720422", "2019-08-30 00:04:10.681242"]}
```

In this last step, unlike the previous one,

```
h[key] ||= []
  #=> ["2019-08-31 02:53:27.720422"] ||= []
  #=> ["2019-08-31 02:53:27.720422"]
```

Comment: I was going to ask an another question about such usage. Thank you. This is worked very well too. In this way I get everything grouped in one shot.